# How to Compare given text and input text?

Tags: javascript

I have a text in my web page and also a textarea for the user to write down his text. Now i need to compare the text in my webpage with the input text. How to do it?

Comment: `text == document.querySelector('textarea').value`

Answer (score 0):

You can get text in textarea element by access `value` attribute.

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/6t0p5e0c/

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the value of text on web page in javascript variable

```
screenText
```

Now you can get the text-area value using

```
var textArea=document.getElementById("textarea_id").value;
```

Now you can compare both the variables by

```
if(textArea==screenText)
 //Success
else
 //Failed Match
```